# How to get data from firebase , before viewdidload

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

i have a problem getting data from firebase.. here is my networking class.

```
class Networking {

static var instance = Networking()


var shopArray : [Shop] = []

func getShops() {

    Database.database().reference().child("eeb3215fgsfnuvj").child("shops").observe(.value) { snapshot in
        let shopsDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        for shop in shopsDictionary.allKeys {

            let tempShopDictionary = shopsDictionary[shop] as! NSDictionary

            self.shopArray.append(Shop(shopID: tempShopDictionary["shop_id"] as! Int, shopName: tempShopDictionary["shop_name"] as! String, shopLat: tempShopDictionary["shop_lat"] as! Double, shopLong: tempShopDictionary["shop_long"] as! Double, shopCategory: tempShopDictionary["shop_category"] as! String, shopLogo: tempShopDictionary["shop_logo"] as! String))

        }
        print(self.shopArray) 

    }

    print(shopArray) // I cant print data here...


}
```

and as I said commend line , I can print data in firebase codeblock but cant print in the line where I added comment

And because of that I cant see my data in view controller.. here is my view controller class.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sideBar: SideBarView!
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var isSideBarOpen : Bool = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    mapView.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    Networking.instance.getShops()
    addMarker()

}




@IBAction func menuButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if isSideBarOpen {

        leadingConstraint.constant = -200

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    } else {
        leadingConstraint.constant = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }

    isSideBarOpen = !isSideBarOpen

}


func addMarker () {

    for marker in Networking.instance.shopArray {
        print(marker)
    }

    // I cant print marker as well


}
```

In addMarker function you will see my comment line. In the function shopArray has no items even it has in Networking class.

Can anybody help me ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database SDK is asynchronous, so when you're adding that `observe` call you're saying: "any time there are updates to this path, call this code block".

Where you have the comment is the line right after you *add* the observer, not right after the observer runs. When you go to add markers, you don't have any data to add yet. You have to make it so that the `addMarker` call is triggered when `shopArray` is updated. You could pass a callback in to `getShops()`, or you could move your observer into your view controller where it can see the `addMarker` function directly.

Once you have it working and understand the concept, it'll be easier to refactor to fit your architecture. Take a look at [Doug's medium post](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) about why the APIs are async to learn more.